# asp.net showing Maxlength on TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use this nice little code: http://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/. 
I'm really new to asp.net programming and I don't know how to use this in my project. My Textboxes are already created and the MaxLength attribute is set to my desired value. Can someone tell me why it's not working.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="20" onfocus="show()"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text\javascript">
    function show(){
    $('input[TextBox1]').maxlength();  
    }
</script>
```

The needed javascript files are referenced in the master file!

Comment: The github page literally explains how to implement the plugin

Comment: For me its not clear at all =(. I linked the needed files for sure but now I really don't know how. Please help me if you know how.

Comment: $("#textBoxID").maxlength();

Answer (score 2):

ref the maxlength.js file

```
<script src="../bootstrap-maxlength/bootstrap-maxlength.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="25" name="alloptions" id="alloptions">


$('input.className').maxlength({
   alwaysShow: true,
   threshold: 10,
   warningClass: "label label-success",
   limitReachedClass: "label label-danger",
   separator: ' of ',
   preText: 'You have ',
   postText: ' chars remaining.',
   validate: true
 });
```

[See Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/k8gqx6sh/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have jQuery and the maxlength plugin referenced all you need to do is add script to your page as follows:

```
<script type="text\javascript">$('input[YOUR_FIELD_ID]').maxlength();</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is where I have to add this line? Ty

Comment: within a script block (preferably after the body element). I have edited the answer.

Comment: after hours of testing I still can't find the answer. Is it possible that it just does not work in asp? I think the problem is that the javascript function will never be called. How can I test this?

Comment: Show what you got so far. Help us help you :)

Comment: I have edited my question. There is the code which I already have

Answer (score 0):

Remove MaxLength attribute from TextBox control
And
Define MaxLength in javascitp function like below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id*=TextBox1]").maxlength({
            alwaysShow: true,
            validate: true,
            allowOverMax: false,
            customMaxAttribute: "100"
        });
    });
</script>
```